# MDI child shows icon when maximized

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, mdichild, controlbox

I have an MDI parent and MDI child. I want to hide the icon of the child form in a maximized state, so I tried the following:

```
g.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
g.ShowIcon = false;
g.Show();
g.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

The `showicon` value of the child form is set to `false`, but when it's maximized, it still shows an icon:

[image]

Comment: Have you written any code on Resize event.

Comment: i set showicon to false in there, too but still not working...

Comment: Check the property of ShowIcon  in window resize.

Comment: Here is the link 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872740/i-want-to-remove-icon-from-windows-mdi-child-form][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872740/i-want-to-remove-icon-from-windows-mdi-child-form

Comment: It says false but it still shows it. I think it is a bug!

Comment: @RajeshSubramanian if i cant do anything i will do this way.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888865/problem-with-icon-on-creating-new-maximized-mdi-child-form-in-net

Comment: @RajeshSubramanian found link I was looking for :)

Comment: @Romil i have seen it but it is not my problems answer. tried it, too.

Comment: Tried hiding the border, FormBorderStyle.None?

Comment: @NicoBeemster yes but when maximized it is not working

Answer (score 3):

MDI requires these frame decorations to be present, it will misbehave in various ways when you try to hide them.  A simple workaround is to create an icon that's entirely transparent.

Answer (score 0):

In the `ItemAdded` event:

```
if (e.item.Text == "" )
{

    e.item.Visible = false;

}
```